# Sending specific data to json file from angularJS app using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I have a Library angularJS application and a JSON Data file that contains an array of book's information like this

```
[
{
    "name" : "test1",
    "pages": 0,
    "author": "author1",
    "year": 1940,
    "section": "history",
    "current": 0,
    "description": "bla bla bla",
    "bookUrl": "data/book.pdf"
},
{
    "name" : "test1",
    "pages": 0,
    "author": "author1",
    "year": 1940,
    "section": "history",
    "current": 0,
    "description": "bla bla bla",
    "bookUrl": "data/book.pdf"
}
]
```

"current" is for the current page of the current book that i'm reading
and there is a "next" and "prev" buttons in the reading view 
when i press "next" it adds "+1" to the "current" num page
the question is **(How to send this +1 to the "current" in JSON file with PHP?)** 
I have this PHP code :

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('library.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$data[0]['current'] = 3;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('library.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

See the ($data[0]) is for the index of the first book, **how do i send to PHP the index of the current book so it updates the "current" data of the current book?**
Here is the "next" function :

```
scope.goNext = function() {
      if (scope.pageToDisplay >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
        return;
      }
      scope.pageNum = parseInt(scope.pageNum) + 1;
        $http.get("data/insert.php")
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("data inserted successfully");
        });
    };
```

And here is the reading Controller :

```
 app.controller('read', ['$scope','books', '$routeParams',function($scope,books, $routeParams) {
  books.success(function(data){
    $scope.book = data[$routeParams.bookId]
    $scope.pdfUrl = data[$routeParams.bookId].bookUrl;
    $scope.pdfName = data[$routeParams.bookId].name;
  });
//the pdf viewer options 
    //$scope.pdfUrl = 'data/tohfa12.pdf';
    $scope.scroll = 0;
    $scope.loading = 'Loading file please wait';
    $scope.getNavStyle = function(scroll) {
        if(scroll > 100) {
            return 'pdf-controls fixed';
        } else {
            return 'pdf-controls';
        }
    };
    $scope.onError = function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    };
    $scope.onLoad = function() {
        $scope.loading = '';
    };
    $scope.onProgress = function(progress) {
        console.log(progress);
    };
  $scope.currentBookIndex = parseInt($routeParams.bookId);
}]);
```

I know it's complicated but i really need that , thanks.

Comment: Do you want implement pagination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect your application to behave?

You need to send the `bookId` and the `pageNum` with your request!

```
scope.goNext = function() {
  if (scope.pageToDisplay >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  scope.pageNum = parseInt(scope.pageNum) + 1;
    $http.get("data/insert.php", {
            param : { 
                bookId: $scope.bookId,
                pageNum: $scope.pageNum
            }
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("data inserted successfully");
        });
};
```

BTW. By REST design a GET http request should never change a resource. GET is for READING. If you want to update a resource you should use POST, PUT or DELETE

Comment: Hey, thanks alot .. I want to know what was the last page i was reading so i could continue from there, so when i press "next" it moves to the next page and add +1 to the current page then send this +1 to the json file .. and i don't know much about PHP .. almost nothing .. sso.. how do i put the param in the PHP code ? do i use them like this $data[$scope.bookId]['current'] = $scope.pageNum; ?

Comment: Then you should learn about PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php